# What is pros and cons of MVVM (Model,View,ViewModel) architecture when compared with other architectures?

Tags: mvvm

What is pros and cons of MVVM (Model,View,ViewModel) architecture when compared with other architectures

Comment: There is no "best" architecture. There are architectural problems and solutions for these problems. It is the same as asking, is hammer the best tool? Is bike the best mean of transportation?

Comment: Oh...sorry...Then how should I ask this? @FCin

Comment: I have to explore whether there is an  architecture which gives more benefits when compared to MVVM Architecture @FCin

Comment: I'm afraid, no matter how you ask it, it will always be opinion based and someone will close your question because it is off-topic([ask]). But look at what pros and cons different architectures give you, look at what your current problem needs and match with the correct architecture...

Comment: oh..okay..Thank you. I edited my question now @FCin